# Head movement technique

Tags: technique, boxing

So I've been boxing for a while now and I've learnt how to slip and weave, not that I'm very good at the technique. The way I've learnt it though, is that you mainly squat while pivoting to your back and lead foot for slipping; not gonna in too much detail. For weaving I just step widen my stance quickly and squat but then go back to normal stance etc. However when I watch boxers they seem to lean a lot or duck like mayweather.

Is this kind of head movement good technique?

It seems rather easy to do, I'm probably wrong and there's more to it but I don't know what that is.

Comment: Charlie, do we need a mod to help you group your accounts together?

Comment: What are you talking about

Comment: These other accounts also look like you, both in user name and type of question. 
http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/users/6846/charlie http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/users/6587/charlie

Comment: Pretty sure that's the same account

Comment: You can request a merge of user accounts by [contacting Stack Exchange](http://stackoverflow.com/contact). Select "I need to merge user profiles" and enter your email and the two profile links and submit the information.

Comment: Charlie, I don't know if you've done it yet but I've just filed a request to merge these accounts - this was before I saw Matt's comment. It should be actioned in a day or two - the two older accounts will be merged with this one.

Comment: I'm sure they're all the same account but whatever, as long as it isn't a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaning/ducking is bad technique for amateurs, let alone most pros. Leaning puts you off balance, and unless you have as much control over your balance and weight as Mayweather, it's really bad for you. You will have no snap in your punches and you will go down more easily.

Practice head movement while shadowboxing, i.e. double jab, then move head to the left. Constantly move the head, and practice it while sparring too - everytime you jab or move, move your head a bit. Just an inch might work well, especially if you roll with the punches.

Comment: Why do people do it then?

Comment: Because it CAN have an advantage, but unless you're at the very top both athletically and in terms of talent, the potential benefit you could achieve from doing so does not outweigh the potential bad consequences. It's like switching southpaw from orthodox; yes it looks fancy, and yes it can work well. But as a beginner/novice, it'll just hinder your progress and doesn't work in your favor at all.

Comment: What's the advantage

Comment: Slick head movement and changing the distance to your opponent. But it's nullified if you don't have speed/reaction to utilize it at all. If you look at Floyd, he will roll with the punches that way, making punches hit less hard.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand

Comment: Are you saying that leaning/ ducking gives you those advantages? I'm confused how and how they're such big advantages

Comment: It can, if you are as fast as Mayweather or the like, meaning, most people will only have disadvantages for doing this. Which is why trainers discourage it.

Comment: So most boxers who do it, probably shouldn't I guess

Comment: Why do most boxers do it tho